# Laravel get Model siblings and self - is this the right way?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an Eloquent model which has these functions:

```php
<?php

class Package extends Model
{

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( Package::class, 'parent_id' );
    }

    public function childs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany( Package::class, 'parent_id' );
    }

    /**
     * All packages that belongs to each other
     */
    public function siblings_and_self()
    {
        $result = $this->newCollection()->add( $this );
        $result = $result->merge( $this->parent()->get() );
        $result = $result->merge( $this->childs()->get() );

        return $result;
    }
}
```

It is about the last function `siblings_and_self` and I am curious if this is the correct way to retrieve the result.

Or would you suggest another method retrieving all related records and self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be improved.

Instead of:

```
$result->merge( $this->parent()->get() );
```

you should rather use:

```
$result->merge([$this->parent]);
```

Also instead of

```
$this->childs()->get()
```

you can use:

```
$this->childs
```

So finally you can simplify it and use just:

```
public function siblings_and_self()
{
    return $this->newCollection([$this, $this->parent])->merge( $this->childs );
}
```

However if case you want to use this on multiple model, you should first eager load `parent` and `childs` relationships to avoid `n+1` queries problem like this:

```
// here you eager load
$packages = Package::with('parent', 'childs')->get();


// and now you can use it
foreach ($packages as $package)
{
   $siblings_and_self = $package->siblings_and_self();
  // and now you can do something with this variable
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However when an item is parent, then `$this->parent` is empty, and I get an error. Also, if an item is sibling itself, it would not get the other siblings. I am trying to get them via parent.childs (which can also be empty in other cases) in a `Package` model function, which is hard I think.

Comment: In such case you can add some custom logic . For example You can add parent into collection only when  `if ($this->parent)`

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are willing to do with the data, but you could use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to make your query look nicer.

```
$package = Package::where('id', 5)->with(['parent', 'childs'])->get();
```

Now you can use the `parent` and `child` properties to find the related data

```
// The id of the current package
echo $package->id; 

// The id of the parent package
echo $package->parent->id;

// The id of the first child package
echo $package->childs->first()->id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However I want to get them at once in one collection. Also when an item is sibling, then `childs` is empty, and we have to get the childs via the parent.